# cake php calling function of controller and getting controller could not be found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am learning cake php . I made plugin with folder name Map , every thing goes fine . but when i call other function then `index()` in `MapController` class . it gives error

> Map.functionName could not be found.

but i made that function in `MapController` class .

```
url -- http://localhost/rootfolder/map/functionName
```

Please tell whats the problem. Can we not able to make other function than `index()` in plugin ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plugins, the default URL path is `/:plugin/:controller/:action`, so you'll probably need to access `/map/map/action`. This can be re-written with routes like so:

```
Router::connect('/something/', array('plugin' => 'map', 'controller' => 'map', 'action' => 'someACtion'));
```

Comment: how to override this behaviour ?

Comment: thanks it works but please tell can we change this behaviour ?

Comment: Routes! I have put a simple example in my answer.